# audacity noise removal without using noise-only portion of the song

Tags: audacity

I cannot use the noise reduction tool built in audacity because it needs a portion of the song where there is only noise. In the songs I have (old tango recordings), there is no empty part before or after the song but during the song, there is a constant hum/hiss. How can I improve the sound and reduce the noise in such a situation?

For example in the pictures below there is hum/hiss constantly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Izotope RX has a spectral de-noiser that will auto-learn and therefore doesn't need a noise pattern to teach it.